# Emacs tramp on chroot directory

Tags: tramp

I have chroot directory.
When I try to open `/ssh:web@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/`, Emacs returns “Found remote shell prompt on”.
From console I login to directory.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by chroot directory? Does tramp work when not using that chroot?

Comment: /ssh:root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ -> work

/ssh:web@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ -> Found remote shell prompt on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: from console: ssh web@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -> work